# WebRTC local stream disappears on HTML input click

Tags: webrtc, goinstant, goinstant-platform

The WebRTC stream seems to all be working fine at first with everyone in the conference. Unfortunately, when you click on certain HTML elements the local stream video disappears.

You are still able to see the remote users and remote users can both see/hear you but you are unable to see yourself.

Once the local stream has disappeared, destroying and re-initializing the connection/WebRTC widget won't make the local video reappear. The browser needs to be refreshed but clicking on the HTML element causes the same problem to appear again.

There are no javascript errors and the only thing on the HTML element is a focus event which sets a local variable (it's not doing anything crazy).

Is there anything I can do to stop this?

```
    goinstant.connect(url, function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        var room = connection.room("new_room_id");

        room.join(function(err) {
            room.self().key("displayName").set("my_username");

            var stun = {
                url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
            };

            var turn = {
                url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
                username: 'turn@username.com',
                credential: 'password'
            };

            that._webrtc = new goinstant.widgets.WebRTC({
                room: room,
                autoStart: true,
                peerConnectionConfig: {
                    iceServers: [stun, turn]
                }
            });

            webrtc.initialize(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error starting video: " + err);
                }
                else {
                    $(".gi-webrtc").draggable();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Only can say anything after view your code, So post your code first.

Comment: I've added the code I use to set up the connection. The app is build using backbone.js

Comment: We tried reproducing this locally with jQuery#draggable but was unsuccessful. Is there a live demo of your app that we can use for debugging this issue?

Comment: Most definitely! Here's a link to a board that you can debug on http://gamestorming-10443.onmodulus.net/board/533acfb6c32f5e000000000d

Comment: If you try removing the class 'gi-stream' from the video element like so $('.gi-local video').attr('class', '') this stops happening. Is it possible that you have some code that interacts with the video element  via its className when you click the chat textarea?

Comment: Update. The problem is caused by the "-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1)" style. This causes the video element to not render when you click the textarea, appears to be a bug with webkit-transform on a video element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when you click on a textarea on the page.

Removing the "-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1)" style from the video in the HTML stops this from occurring.